# Pandas group coma separated words with second column then groupby and sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns.  `report_tags` is comma separated words, and `t_f` is a flag for yes or no(1 or 0).  I would like to separate these comma separated words and group by `t_f`.  Then sum the `tag/t_f` groupings in a new column called `count`

```
df 
    report_tags             t_f
0   bec,eac,fbi,ic3,scam    1
1   dlink,router,wifi       0
2   adobe                   0
3   bec, fbi                1
4   bec, fbi, scam          0
```

Desired output:

```
df2
   tag    t_f   count
0  bec    1     2
1  eac    1     1
2  fbi    1     2
3  ic3    1     1
4  scam   1     1
5  dlink  0     1
6  router 0     1
7  wifi   0     1
8  adobe  0     1
9  bec    0     1
10 fbi    0     1
11 scam   0     1
```

Comment: Use `df.explode` and the rest should follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.split` + `explode`

---

```
k = dict(sort=False)

(df.set_index('t_f')['report_tags']
  .str.split(r',\s*').explode()
  .groupby(level=0, **k).value_counts(**k)
  .rename('count').reset_index())
```

```
    t_f report_tags  count
0     1         bec      2
1     1         eac      1
2     1         fbi      2
3     1         ic3      1
4     1        scam      1
5     0       adobe      1
6     0         bec      1
7     0       dlink      1
8     0         fbi      1
9     0      router      1
10    0        scam      1
11    0        wifi      1
```

Comment: I like this but keep getting the error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'` .  This line that it is pointing out is `.str.split(r',\s*').explode()` @user3483203

Comment: @sectechguy: you need to update to pandas 0.25+ to have `explode`